# is sub-partitioning allowed in Google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud, partitioning

Does sub-partitioning feature exist in Google Bigquery. From the docs it looks like it doesn't exist. Please let me know if anyone has used it. Thanks.

Referral doc-https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Sub partitioning" isn't a feature, but you can create [clustered tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables).
You can create partitioned + clustered tables that essentially give you a primary index (partition key) and secondary indices (cluster keys).

There is a [great section in GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables#combinine-clustered-partitioned-tables) that visualises how the data will be stored for a table that uses partitioning and clustering.

Comment: okay. Thanks. Just wanted to confirm sub partitioning is not a feature in GCP. But clustering helps.